# Setting h:inputText value on a nested property doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Given the following Java class A:

```
public class A {

    private String s1;

    private String s2;

    ///  getters and setters

}
```

I would like to use it as a member of a JSF Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    private A a;

    public A getA () {
        return a;
    } 

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

To be able in the .xhtml to use it in the following way:

```
<h:inputText id="s1" value="#{bean.a.s1}" />  
<h:inputText id="s2" value="#{bean.a.s2}" />
```

This didn't work for me, is it possible? Otherwise I will have to declare each member of A in the class Bean.

Comment: well, it should work. At least works for me. Maybe you're forgetting to create a new instance of A? like private A a = new A();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your managedbean should be initial object like Leo said.

Alternative, Initial your object by constructor

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    private A a;

    public Bean(){
        a = new A();
    }

    public A getA () {
        return a;
    } 

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

or postConstruct

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean {

    private A a;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        a = new A();
    }

    public A getA () {
        return a;
    } 

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```